Don't understand why SynchronizationContext in WinForm don't captured
I wrote simple example on WinForm:
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

     await foo().ConfigureAwait(true);
     textBox1.Text += "\\r\\n Current thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
     textBox1.Invalidate();

}
private async  Task  foo()
{
     textBox1.Text += "Current thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
     HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
     await await client.GetStringAsync("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1").ContinueWith<Task>(async (p) =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(100_000).ConfigureAwait(true);
                textBox1.Text += "\\r\\n Current thread SecondContinueWith: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
            }
           ).ConfigureAwait(true);
    textBox1.Text += "\\r\\n Current thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
}

This code write to textBox1 output:

"Current thread: 1
Current thread SecondContinueWith: 14
Current thread: 1
Current thread: 1".

But I expected that continuation in ContinueWith will capture WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext and will execute in UI Thread. But continuation print another ThreadId   without debug mode and in Debug mode throw IvalidationException  thus continuation execute in another thread from threadpool. Why continuation don't capture context?When I miss context? Why continuation execute in another thread then UI thread?
Note: When I explicity use  SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext in continuation, continuation execute in UI thread as expecting.

Mixing await with ContinueWith does not enhance clarity of code. I would avoid it.

You need to specify TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously.

The ContinueWith method by default executes the continuationAction on the ambient TaskScheduler.Current. In your case this is equal to the TaskScheduler.Default, because your code is not running inside another Task configured with a non-default scheduler. The TaskScheduler.Default is associated with the ThreadPool, so the continuationAction is invoked on the ThreadPool. If you want to invoke it on the UI thread, you must configure the ContinueWith with a scheduler associated with the UI thread. You can get such a scheduler with the help of the method TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext. In that case your code will look something like this (not tested):
textBox1.Text += "Current thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

TaskScheduler ui = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

await await client.GetStringAsync("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1").ContinueWith<Task>(async t =>
{
    await Task.Delay(100_000).ConfigureAwait(true);
    textBox1.Text += "\\r\\n Current thread SecondContinueWith: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
}, ui).ConfigureAwait(true);

textBox1.Text += "\\r\\n Current thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;

As a side note, Microsoft recommends to specify always the scheduler parameter, whenever you use the ContinueWith method.

ContinueWith is a low-level primitive. It doesn't automatically capture the current SynchronizationContext. It's much harder to use ContinueWith correctly than to use await correctly.
Since you're already using await, just keep using await:
textBox1.Text += "Current thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var p = await client.GetStringAsync("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1");
textBox1.Text += "\\r\\n Current thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;

await Task.Delay(100_000);
textBox1.Text += "\\r\\n Current thread: " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;

